# How Do I keep mail() from waiting for confirmation (true)

Tags: php, email

i have a php script that sends out my messages using mail(). the problem is that it waits until it receives confirmation from the mailer before it continues... I'd like to skip this step. is there a way to set it as true by default or have it not wait, etc? below is the section of code I'm referring to. Thanks.

```
        if (file_exists($attachment)) {
        sendmail_attach_new($email, $subject, $msg_text, $msg, $attachment, $mailheaders, "$from_name <$from_email>");
    } elseif ($msg) {
        if( ini_get('safe_mode') ){
            mail($email, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);
        }else{
            mail($email, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders, "-f$from_email");
        }
    } elseif ($msg_text) {
        if( ini_get('safe_mode') ){
            mail($email, $subject, $msg_text, $mailheaders);
        }else{
            mail($email, $subject, $msg_text, $mailheaders, "-f$from_email");
        }
    }
    //update the mailing list for confirmation of sent mail
    $sql = "update $tableMail set mid ='$mid' where id='$DATA[id]'";
    sql_query($sql);
    $logbuffer .= "Mailed: $email<br>";
    $row++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can write to stack mails that your must send, and script running by cron, can send it

Comment: This is the obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Btw, don't make your scripts `safe_mode compatible. Any host that still uses this deprecated mis-feature should be avoided anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can externalize your mail sending code to a separate php script and call that script using exec() function, something like this on Unix platforms:

```
exec ("/usr/bin/php send-mail.php \"$from\" \"$to\" \"$subject\" \"$message\" >/dev/null &");
```

To make this background process execution platform independent use code like this:

```
function launchBackgroundProcess($commandLine) {
     // Windows
    if(PHP_OS == ‘WINNT’ || PHP_OS == ‘WIN32′) {
        pclose(popen(’start /b ‘.$commandLine.”, ‘r’));
    }
     // Some sort of UNIX
    else {
        pclose(popen($commandLine.‘ > /dev/null &’, ‘r’));
    }
    return true;
}
```

Refer to this Blog post: http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/10/16/how-to-run-a-php-script-in-the-background/

Comment: Since the OP wants the code to work with safe mode, he can't use `exec`. Otherwise, this would be good solution.

Comment: I don't see 'safe mode' requirement in the question. As I understand the question was just to avoid mail() from blocking. However the sample script OP has included does have check for safe mode to pass additional from address in mail function.

Comment: This won't works, because when parent PHP script is stops, than child PHP script become zombie